# 'vim' is not recognized in cmd if it's opened via explorer address bar?

Tags: vim, cmd, path

I have added `VIM`'s folder to the `PATH` environment variable. So, I can access the editor in any terminal I have simply by typing `vim`. Everything's okay. But there's one peculiarity which puzzles me. It doesn't work. I get

> 'vim' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

in case it was opened/started via the explorer address bar (which is the way I normally do it).

I also have another `VIM` installed as a `Cygwin` package and it doesn't have such "limitation" (I can access it using the same Command Prompt that was opened via the explorer address bar).

What I think can be important here is that the Cygwin and its vim package have been installed with installer. But the other VIM is a nightly build which I downloaded as a zip from `vim.org` (so, it's kind of "portable").

---

Now, I wonder is there anything else I should have done to the system/`vim` itself apart from adding the folder to the `PATH`, so my "portable" VIM work properly inside the Windows (like the `Cygwin` one mentioned above)?

Anything else that may be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Have you closed all Windows Explorer instances after adding VIM folder path to __system__ `PATH`? Or have you even better restarted Windows after adding VIM folder path to __system__ `PATH`? Why? Please read [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) and I hope you understand why restart of Windows is usually the easiest method for a user to get a __system__ `PATH` modification distributed to all processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you change your environment variables, move important system files, perform a disk cleanup, etc. it's highly recommended that you **always perform a restart**, so that the changes are correctly and fully applied.

See also: [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769).